# Swift custom back button in EKEventViewController navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have using EKEventViewController in our app.
Code should like below

```
class MyEkEventViewController: EKEventViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(MyEkEventViewController.cancel))
           self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(cancelButton, animated: false)
          //self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func cancel() {
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}  

   # My invocation   
   .
   .
   .
    let eventViewController = MyEkEventViewController()
        eventViewController.delegate = self
               eventViewController.allowsEditing = true
        eventViewController.allowsCalendarPreview = true
        eventViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        eventViewController.event = event
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventViewController, animated: true)
```

Back arrow only displayed. But Cancel button is not displayed in left side navigation bar.

[image: Sample screen shot here]

Comment: You problem is not 100% understandable.. please try to share screen shot and issue in detail.

Comment: @Dheeraj D , I am added custom cancel button in MyEkEventViewController. The cancel button is not displayed